# Xubuntu 16.04.2 locking/closing lid results in black screen

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, suspend, power-management, laptop

I've Xubuntu 16.04.2 installed on dell laptop(UEFI mode). It's the only OS on it. It has nvidea graphics card, which I think is causing the problem.

Now whenever I lock the screen or close the lid, it ends up in a black screen with '-' symbol in the left top corner. I tried 'ctrl-alt-f1' to login but nothing happens. So I've to hard restart my laptop.

So I tried the following things

- Uninstall light locker and replace it with xscreensaver. Now this solves the locking problem but closing the lid stills results in black screen
- Also tried resetting light locker settings, but nothing happens.

Don't know what to do about it ? Went through all the post and tried their solutions, but nothing works.

---